# Byte initialized reading socket in loop

Tags: vb.net

I'm newbi and trying to write an client code which receives data from the server and output to textbox. 
The problem is when the 2nd **ServerStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length)** in the loop initializes **inStream** values.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ServerStream.Read(inStream, 0, 5)
        ReceivedData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream)
        ServerStream.Flush()

        If (String.Compare(ReceivedData, "_OK_") = 0) Then
            msg(ReceivedData)
            Do
                Dim recv = ServerStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length)
                ReceivedData = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetString(inStream, 0, recv)
                msg(ReceivedData)
                If (String.Compare(ReceivedData, "END") = 0) Then
                    msg("Server closed")
                End If
            Loop While ServerStream.DataAvailable
        Else
            msg("Unable to recieve msg")
        End If

End Sub
```

I'm bushing around the web sites but still don't understand what I've done wrong...

Comment: How do you difine: ServerStream and inStream...

Answer (score 0):

In your first call to `Read`:

```
ServerStream.Read(inStream, 0, 5)
```

You ignore it's return value. It might have only read as little as 1 byte. You do slightly better with your second usage (reading in a loop), but you again seem to be assuming that you'll receive entire "messages" (e.g. `END`) as sent from the other end of the connection.

There are no such guarantees. You need to loop (and keep track of where in the buffer to start writing newly received data) until you detect (somehow) that you've received complete "messages". This would normally be done by:

- prefixing the message with its length, or
- by using a byte value that cannot appear within the messages as an end-of-message marker, or
- sending only fixed-length messages, or
- including a message "type" code at the start of the message, where each message type if a fixed length